# Get data from SQLliteDatabaseHelper in Service class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I have an Application with Service class that run in backgroud and other activity. In the activity when i get data from my database i do:

```
databaseHelper = new DBNotifyHelper(this);
Cursor c = databaseHelper.getNotify(myState, myVariable, myVariable2);
```

where the method getNotify in my DBNotifyHelper is:

```
public Cursor getNotify (String myState, String myVariable, String myVariable2)
{
    return getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Notify WHERE State = ? AND myVariable= ? AND myVariable2= ?", new String[] {myState, myVariable, myVariable2});
}
```

and it work fine,but it doesn't work in Service.How i get the same thing in the Service? I don't use cursor?? please Help Me (Sorry for my english).

Comment: Can you confirm that this code has been runed?

Comment: When you say it 'doesn't work in Service', what happens? Is there a crash? Does logcat have any information?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, the problem migth be because of concurrent access to DB from different threads.  Try using the `Application Context` when instantiating this  SQLiteOpenHelper (constructor parameter), so you do not leak some other Context.

If it doesn't help, please show your `SQLiteOpenHelper` code.

EDIT: click on the string with NullPointerException and give us a string, from which it is thrown.